# sql server 2008 r2 - multiple columns each with sum on dependent variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a query that will sum a dollar amount within a specified time frame and grouped by various factors.  I've stripped down the tables as much as possible for the sake of clarity but there are actually 20 code1's, 50 code2's and 15 identifiers (the identifiers each would have their own results column)

table t

```
code1      code2     date          identifier     dollars
A          a         11/22/18          1             3
B          a         11/23/18          1             4
A          b         11/24/18          1             5
B          b         11/25/18          1             6
A          a         11/22/18          2             7
B          a         11/23/18          2             8
A          b         11/24/18          2             9
B          b         11/25/18          2             10
```

desired output

```
code1    code2     identifier1_sum     identifier2_sum
A        a         3                   7
B        a         4                   8
A        b         5                   9
B        b         6                   10
```

I don't seem to be able to get the grouping and summing to come out correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: There isn't any real aggregation going on here... at least with your sample data. You are simply pivoting the data. In your real data would you need an aggregation? I ask because if there are a lot of identifers (i.e. there will be more than your original 15 moving forward) you'll want a dynamic pivot since dynamic conditional aggregation isn't that easy. Otherwise you can make 15 conditional aggregation columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation here:

```
SELECT
    code1,
    code2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN identifier = 1 THEN dollars ELSE 0 END) AS identifier1_sum,
    SUM(CASE WHEN identifier = 2 THEN dollars ELSE 0 END) AS identifier2_sum
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    code1,
    code2;
```

[image]

### Demo